# SABR system with sdeint

Tags: python, ode, stochastic

I'm trying to implement [SABR volatility model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SABR_volatility_model) using `sdeint` package. Basically, the model consists of two equations

```
dx1 = 0*x1*dt + x2*x1^b*dWt
dx2 = 0*x2*dt + a*x2*dZt
```

I tried to rewrite the second example of the [official documentation](https://pypi.org/project/sdeint/), but I encountered the following issue:

```
SDEValueError: y0 has length 2. So G must either be a single function
              returning a matrix of shape (2, m), or else a list of m separate
              functions each returning a column of G, with shape (2,)
```

My code

```py
import numpy as np
import sdeint

A = np.array([[0, 0],
              [ 0, 0]])
a = 1
b = 0.5

B = np.diag([1, a]).T

tspan = np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, 10001)
x0 = np.array([3.0, 3.0])

def f(x, t):
    return A.dot(x)

def G(x, t):
    BB = np.array([  x[1]*x[0]**b, x[1]  ])
    print(BB)
    return B.dot(BB)

result = sdeint.itoint(f, G, x0, tspan)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, it should be a square diagonal matrix in your case:

```py
def G(x, t):
    BB = np.diag([  x[1]*x[0]**b, x[1] ])
    return BB
```